# Pass a 503 status code through a reverse proxy

Tags: apache-2.4, mod-proxy

I'm getting behavior I don't quite understand from my Apache reverse proxy.

I have a back end server which returns a 503 using `app_offline.htm` during certain processes.

When this occurs I receive a traditional Apache 403 error:

```
You don't have permission to access / on this server.

Additionally, a 403 Forbidden error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.
```

If my back end server is unavailable and mod_proxy can't connect I do see my custom error screen, but a generic 503.. I'm guessing that I need to pass that 503 back from mod_proxy to Apache for handling, but I'm not sure how.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding the [`ProxyErrorOverride On`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_proxy.html#proxyerroroverride) to my virtual hosts does allow me to capture this status code and react appropriately. The problem is this also redirects all of our other status codes.

I'm using a couple small pass throughs to display the contents on the back side if I get a 404 or the like.

ErrorDocument 404 404.html

Contents of 404.html

```
<html style="height: 100%">
<body style="height: 100%">
    <div style="width:100%; height:100%; background-color:transparent;">
    <iframe src="https://xxxxx.com/PageNotFound.aspx" width="100%" height="100%" frameborder="0" scrolling="no"></iframe>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```